# How to create BTS index in Informix

Tags: informix

I have problem with creating BTS (basic text search) index in Informix. I have created test table and sbspace to store index information just like it is in documentation. Now my sbspace looks like:

```
[informix@test-informix informix]$ onspaces -c -S bts_sbspace -p  /home/informix/chunks/bts_sbspace -o 0 -s 1500000 -Df "LOGGING=ON"
...
[informix@test-informix informix]$ onstat -d | grep SB
ed682820         7        0x68001    7        3        2048     N SB     informix sbspace
fd409e00         14       0x68001    73       1        2048     N SB     informix bts_sbspace
ed8c1028         7      7      0          50000      43896      44061      POSBD /home/informix/IFMXDATA/ol_testifx/sbspacedbs.000
edb82db8         30     7      0          500000     466235     466319     POSBD /home/informix/IFMXDATA/ol_testifx/sbspacedbs.001
ee7fe028         31     7      0          500000     466306     466319     POSBD /home/informix/IFMXDATA/ol_testifx/sbspacedbs.002
fd40de00         73     14     0          750000     699446     699446     POSBD /home/informix/chunks/bts_sbspace
```

But when I want to create index:

```
CREATE INDEX lab1_bts_index ON lab1(text_data bts_lvarchar_ops) USING BTS IN bts_sbspace;
```

it ends with error:

```
Error: bts internal error.  File c/bts_am_extspace.c, line 505
SQLState:  BTS02
ErrorCode: -937
Position: 88
```

I use `IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC4` with `bts2.0` registered for test database.

How can I create BTS index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example work's fine on my 11.50uc7 but with a different table schema.
May be you hit the bug IC81229.

```
onmode -p +1 bts
echo "register bts.2.00 stores"|blademgr
onspaces -c -S bts_sbspace -p  /home/informix/ids1150uc7/bts_sbspace -o 0 -s 2000 -Df "LOGGING=ON"
create table tclob (id integer,c  clob);
create index ixclob on tclob (c bts_clob_ops) using bts in bts_sbspace
```

Comment: It seems that this database was dbexported/dbimported and some BTS tables are in wrong state so registering/unregistering BTS even when it says "success" really do not work. I was able to create BTS index on another, fresh database.